# How can I submit hidden field value when I'm calling my ActionResult from my a href

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to get request url (the Url of the Page/ActionMethod coming from)

As you can see guys when I click on any of my `a href` I'm calling `ApplySelectedLanguage` `ActionResult` from my `Language` controller.

I wanted to solve this by adding one hidden field which would be submitted and I could read the path easily,
something like this : "`<%= Html.Hidden("requestUrl", Request.RawUrl) %>`"

But I don't know where this can fit in this example so I could post it back

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu custom-dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="@Url.Action("ApplySelectedLanguage", "Language", new { Lcid = "1050" })"><%= Html.Hidden("requestUrl", Request.RawUrl) %>EN</a></li>
    <li><a href="@Url.Action("ApplySelectedLanguage", "Language", new { Lcid = "3098" })"><%= Html.Hidden("requestUrl", Request.RawUrl) %>DE</a></li>
</ul>
```

I know it might be solved on server side using

`HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer`,

but I would like to solve it with hidden field.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ApplySelectedLanguage(string requestUrl, int Lcid)
{
    // requestUrl will contain the url of the page used to 
    // render the form
    ...
}
```

Comment: A hidden input is not necessary - just use `"@Url.Action("ApplySelectedLanguage", "Language", new { Lcid = "1050", requestUrl =  Request.RawUrl })"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `Html.Hidden("requestUrl", Request.RawUrl)` value in `href` attribute like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.dropdown-menu.custom-dropdown-menu').find('a').attr("href", function () {
            return this.href + $('#requestUrl').val();
        });
    });
</script>
```

But as @Stephen Muecke said better way is add `requestUrl` to `@Url.Action` like this:

```
href = "@Url.Action("ApplySelectedLanguage", "Language", new { Lcid = "1050", requestUrl = Request.RawUrl })"
```